# Clickonce installer

Tags: visual-c++, ms-word, clickonce, web-platform-installer

I've created MS Word 2007 application using ClickOnce as installer in MSVC2010, my question is whether such an application is free for commercial usage.If not what criteria do I or my client have to match?

Thank you